# How to scroll to a certain section in a page without using href attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css

My navigation bar is self populated with javascript.

```
function liCreation() {
   for(noOfSection of noOfsections) {
       sectionAddress = noOfSection.getAttribute('data-nav');
       section =noOfSection.getAttribute('id');
       liTag = document.createElement('li');
       liTag.innerHTML = `<a class='menu__link'>${sectionAddress}</a>`;
}
}
```

So it comes out with a navigation bar menu that has 4 sections (because I got 4 sections in my page)
I want to scroll to a section without adding `href="${section}"` to the anchor element.

Answer (score 1):

Why? It gives several benefits. Href shows the arrow pointer and no code is needed to scroll

If you must, then

```
document.querySelector("ul.nav").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
   const tgt = e.target;
   if (tgt.tagname === "A" && tgt.classList.contains("menu__link")) {
      document.getElementById(tgt.textContent.trim()).scrollIntoView();
   }
})
```

assuming the id is in the text of the anchor and the ul containing the LIs have a class of .nav